# Set timeout for each thread in a java threadPool

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice

I want to set timeout for each thread(non future.get(time,unit)) which are executed within a thread pool. At the moment I have following code:

```
private static void rpcService() throws Exception{
    long s = System.currentTimeMillis();
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100);//
    long e = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if(e-s > 100){
        System.out.println((e-s) + " MILLISECONDS");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(500);
    while (true) {
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1);
        service.submit(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    //the rpc timeout is 100 milliseconds
                    rpcService();
                } catch (Exception e) {}
            }
        });
    }
}
```

why the output is the following：

```
139 MILLISECONDS
133 MILLISECONDS
129 MILLISECONDS
128 MILLISECONDS
127 MILLISECONDS
126 MILLISECONDS
125 MILLISECONDS
123 MILLISECONDS
122 MILLISECONDS
121 MILLISECONDS
151 MILLISECONDS
......
```

Comment: Lots of things are happening on your computer between the first call of current time and the last besides just the 100 millisecond sleep. These other things are variable in time.

Answer (score 1):

`System.currentTimeMillis()` is not an accurate method of measuring duration. You should prefer `System.nanoTime()`

But also there's more going on than just the time taken to `sleep`, you have 500 threads competing for however many cores you have, so there's going to be a fair bit of context switching. If you used a https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor() you'd get pretty close to the sleep time.

Answer (score 0):

Because [`Thread.sleep()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep-long-) is:

> subject to the precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers.

It is not a real-time guarantee.